# How can I set Conkeror as my default brower?

Tags: arch-linux, browser, stumpwm

I use the latest Archlinux and [stumpwm](https://stumpwm.github.io/) as my window manager with some Gnome goodies on the side (gnome-power-manager, gnome-settings-daemon and networkmanager applet).
I tried to make Conkeror my default browser. I tried gconftool-2 and changed the 
`/desktop/gnome/url-handlers/http(s)` to `conkeror %s` with no luck.

From what I understand Gconf is migrating to GSettings in Gnome 3 but I am completely lost as to how to configure it. I logged in to a gnome-shell session and tried to change the preferred applications but the only available choices are FireFox and Epiphany.  I've being googling for the past 2 hours without luck and resorted to the hardcore solution of symlinking `/usr/bin/firefox` to `/usr/bin/conkeror`.

Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure if this is the proper way to do it, but it worked for me:

Make sure `/usr/share/applications/conkeror.desktop` contains something like the following:

```
MimeType=text/html;text/xml;application/xhtml_xml;x-scheme-handler/http;x-scheme-handler/https;
```

then run

```
$ sudo update-desktop-database
```

and finally go to System Settings -> System Info -> Default Applications. Check the available applications for "Web"--Conkeror should be listed.

Comment: Thank you, I'll try your solution as soon as I decide to install gnome on my system again. Very disappointed with the "one size fits all" approach of gnome 3. Very happy with arch and stumpwm.

Comment: Thanks!!  This was driving me crazy.  (Seems like it was much easier on earlier versions of Ubuntu....)